# Core Data - accessing instances in a to many relationship vs fetch request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, database-performance

I have a Core Data model in my app with a 'Notebook' entity. 
There are two ways I could access one or many 'Notebook' instances:

- By executing an NSFetchRequest with a predicate asking for an instance with a specific 'title' or 'index' attribute.
- By adding an 'AppData' entity in my Core Data model, forgo the 'index' attribute in 'Notebook' and instead have a to-many ordered relationship from 'AppData' to 'Notebook'. Then I would create an 'AppData' instance on the first app launch (and at every launch after that I would fetch request that one and only 'AppData' instance) and access all 'Notebook' instances through its to-many relationship. To access a notebook by title I would use indexOfObjectPassingTest or fast obj-c enumeration, to access by index I would use objectAtIndex.

It is much easier to query an 'AppData' instance for 'Notebook' instances and their attributes than setting up a fetch request to the managed object context each time.

However, which method would be faster? would one method use more memory or stay in memory more time? I read that objects in to-many relationships are loaded lazily, but when would an object in that set be loaded? when would it be unloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AppData` entity seems redundant. You have to fetch it first, so why not fetch all `Notebook` instances instead? The filtering (by title, other ID attributes) would be the same in both scenarios.

A fetch request does not have to be painful:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Notebook"];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
```

Also, depending on the amount of data you can filter these in-memory, or include a predicate in the fetch request.

Definitely, regardless of the scenario, forgo your idea of the "index attribute". Core Data is an object graph, not a database. The only justification for this could be if you need to sync with some external framework or data store that uses unique identifiers.

For convenience, you could create a method in a category of your managed object.

```
+(NSArray*) appNotebooks {
   NSArray * fetchedResults = // fetch the appropriate entities
   return fetchedResults;
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
Notebook.appNotebooks;
```

Comment: If I fetch all notebooks at once, I would be loading the entire file system, which is what I am trying to avoid. I want to know if it's better to use fetch requests with predicates every time I need some notebook instances, or if I can instead use an 'AppData' to-many relationship and load specific instances from that NSOrderedSet. Is accessing an instance in the NSOrderedSet equivalent to a fetch with predicate, or is it more like loading all the notebooks at once in memory, and then filtering in-memory to find the instance I need?

Comment: basically I just think the code to query an NSOrderedSet is much prettier than using fetch requests with predicates and want to know if they are equivalent in the way they perform and load in memory.

Comment: Your question is not logical. If you have non-"AppData" Notebooks you are not using, just delete them. How is accessing the "AppData" notebooks different from accessing all of them? -- And yes, accessing relationship is just like a fetch request with a predicate. Also, you can make fetches very "pretty" by adjusting your modeled object classes and adding fetch methods.

Comment: "How is accessing the "AppData" notebooks different from accessing all of them?" precisely what I wanted to know: if I have all my notebooks in an AppData instance to-many relationship, am I loading them in memory all at once just like by fetching all notebooks through NSFetchRequest without a predicate? Or is the NSOrderedSet loading an instance only when ask for it (when I call objectAtIndex)?

Comment: Well, you will get a full array / set of pointers in both cases, but Core Data uses "faulting" to fetch some attributes or relationships later behind the scenes when they are needed. So, yes, it's the same, no performance difference. If you need memory optimization, go for NSFetchedResultsController.